# How to move files on remote CIFS share into different remote folder using e.g. smbclient

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

I am looking for a linux command to move set of files from one folder to another on windows box remotely.

I tried smbclient, but when I use it for moving files I have to perform two step process:

1. copy remote CIFS files from folder1 to linux box first. - using mget
2. then copy those files to folder2 on remote CIFS - using mput.

Because of the above process, when I have large files it becomes too much time consuming. How do I do this correctly without moving the files through my local machine?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the rename operation on the remote system to move files from current directory to somewhere else.

```
smb: \> md testfolder
smb: \> rename test.mp3 testfolder/test.mp3
smb: \> cd testfolder
smb: \> rename test.mp3 ../test.mp3
```

You must always state the destination file name.

An alternative would be hard-linking the remote file to it's new location, and then deleting the link on the original location.